# jQuery fadeIn fadeOut doesn't work always in the same way

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have a problem with this http://jsfiddle.net/8ePKP/21/
When a link is clicked , I want active div disappears with fadeOut,the div which is selected appears with fadeIn.But animations work differently on forward and backward clicks.I want transitions always be the same.What is wrong with this ?

Comment: Turn off the `overflow:hidden;` on your page container and you'll see what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this CSS:

```
.pages_of_menu{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

.pages_of_menu.active {
    display: block;
}
```

Your JS is right, but it can get better like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var menu_index=-1;
    var menu_pages=$(".pages_of_menu");

    $("#left_panel_div a").click(function(){
          menu_index=$(this).parent('li').index();
          menu_pages.fadeOut(500);
          $($(".pages_of_menu").get(menu_index)).fadeIn(500);
    });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/K5bbL/

Comment: Thanks @Shankar Cabus it is very useful now.But There is a point I dont understand. I edited your codes http://jsfiddle.net/K5bbL/6/   $(menu_pages.get(menu_index)).fadeIn(1000); in this part,How does browser understand which div is in which index ?

Comment: @SedatKURT, the `$(".pages_of_menu")` return an array with 3 `<li>` and as you already know the index of the clicked element, simply retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Your pages need to be absolutely positioned so that they stack.

http://jsfiddle.net/8ePKP/23/

```
.pages_of_menu{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

otherwise you will have to wait until the previous page is faded out completely before you fade in the next one.

Comment: Thanks man.It works nicely.But I must ask , what is .stop(true,true) exactly doing ?

Comment: That prevents your animations from queueing up endlessly when you quickly click the links. Try removing them and clicking the links over and over very quickly.